# Error when passing a variable to another script of project

Tags: python, import

I try to pass the two strings `Start='2018-07-01'`and `End='2019-07-01'` from one script `mainfile.py` to another script `plot.py`.
Here, these dates are used for giving titles to the plots.

```
mainfile.py:
from choose_weatherstation import Choose_Weatherstation
# from summary import scatter_size
#choose_weatherstation is the function: Input has to be
 'Weatherstation',perhour(true/false), weather(false/true)
 save(True/false),statistic (true/False)

Start='2018-09-01'
End='2018-12-31'
Choose_Weatherstation('Zeeland',Start,End,True,True,True,True)
```

```
plot.py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from mainfile import Start, End

Start=mainfile.Start
End=mainfile.End

def three_plot(condition,plot1,plot2,plot3,filename,Save=False):
...(Not of interest here)
```

From what I read in other threads, I tried to import these two variables with the following:

```
from mainfile import Start, End
```

However, as I do this, the following error occurs `cannot import name 'Choose_Weatherstation' from 'choose_weatherstation' (L:\Improved Code\venv\choose_weatherstation.py)` 
This refers to the first line of script `mainfile.py`, where I import `Choose_Weatherstation from choose_weatherstation.py`.

When I do NOT try to import `Start` and `End`, no errors are found.

Can anyone explain me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you post the both scripts here, it is not clear from above context

Comment: How looks your **choose_weatherstation** module?

Answer (score 1):

#### The correct syntax is:

```py
from mainfile import Start, End
```

So, literally, "from mainfile.py import the "Start" and "End" object.
Looks like you have correct imports.

You do not have to call:

```py
Start=mainfile.Start
End=mainfile.End
```

if you have imported variables straight from the module. Just pass it as you imported it:

```py
start, end = Start, End
```

#### Errors you may have:

- You probably have the wrong path to the imported module (enter the full path if you do not work for example in the package),
- You are importing the wrong object name (you should probably write the function name with a lowercase letter). Based on your comments.

#### You can also pay attention to these things:

See [Google Python Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html)

**Examples of naming objects**:

> module_name, package_name, ClassName, method_name, ExceptionName, function_name, GLOBAL_CONSTANT_NAME, global_var_name, instance_var_name, function_parameter_name, local_var_name

Comment: Hi Karol, thanks for your effort! The weird thing is that without the "mainfile import, the whole code runs fine and at the moment I add this very line, the "Choose_Weatherstation" is no longer found. I worked around the problem now by passing the parameters via the functions. The remark about writestyle is a good one! Thanks for that!